# Where do I find Post Money Valuations of Private Companies?

Tags: stock-valuation, private-company

Where do I find Post Money Valuations of Private Companies?

Ideally a free website, but paid ones would be fine too.

Sometimes Crunchbase has them and sometimes they don't. For example, what is Wealthfront's latest post money valuation and where did you find it?

Bonus points if they look pretty and you can search for private companies.

Answer (score 4):

This information is, well... Private.

Some companies make it known publicly, others don't. Valuations are not done frequently, only during financing rounds, so even published information can be very stale.

Bottom line- what you're looking for doesn't exist.